# create functions dynamically in js

Tags: javascript, vuex

I am trying to learn some javascript best practices when writing repetitive functions that can
be declared dynamically... I managed to do it in my getters and mutations but I find it hard to do in the actions object (see code below).

```
import Vue from "vue"

const states = {
  scene: null,
  dataInfoItems: null
}

const getterObjects = {}
const mutationObjects = {}
const actionObjects = {}
Object.keys(states).forEach(key => {
  getterObjects[key] = state => state[key]
  mutationObjects[key] = (state, value) => (state[key] = value)
})

export const state = () => states

export const getters = {
  ...getterObjects
}

export const mutations = {
  ...mutationObjects
}

export const actions = {
  setScene({ commit }, scene) {
    commit("scene", scene)
  },
  setDataInfoItems({ commit }, dataInfoItems) {
    commit("dataInfoItems", dataInfoItems)
  }
}
```

Comment: You could simply omit the `set*` prefix on the actions like you have for mutations and getters and use the same approach as you did for mutations, eg `actionObjects[key] = (({ commit }, value) => (commit(key, value))`

Comment: That being said, both your getters and actions appear to be completely redundant here so why bother?